# Struggling with curl and bash

Tags: bash

There's a `bash` script for uploading pastes to a pastebin server you own and run, specifically this:

```
haste() { a=$(cat); curl -X POST -s -d "$a" http://example.com/documents | awk -F '"' '{print "http://example.com/"$4}'; }
```

However, when attempting to use it in my `.bashrc` after updating the URL, I get errors similar to the following:

```
user@domain:~$ curl -X POST -d 'test' example.com /home/user/test.txt https://example.com | awk -F '"' '{print "https://example.com/"$4}'
% Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100    18  100    14  100     4    127     36 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--   128
chttps://example.com/
url: (3) <url> malformed
100    18  100    14  100     4     33      9 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--    40
```

I've tried variations of this, like leaving out `-X` and `-s` as well as modifying the `$4` variable. Frankly, I'm at a loss as to what I'm doing wrong here.

I've also been trying to work it down to where I just do the following:

```
curl -F file=@/home/user/example.txt example.com
```

but I'm not sure if that's even possible.

Is there even a Pastebin service that can do this that I can run?

Edit: Getting closer. Sort of.

```
user@example:~$ curl  -X POST example.txt -d 'test' https://example.com | awk -F '"' '{print "https://example.com/"$4}'
% Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     
0curl: (6) Could not resolve host: example.txt
100    18  100    14  100     4     31      8 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--    70
https://example.com/
```

Seems like maybe I should use the -F bit here for the example.txt?

Comment: You can use `curl -X POST -d@- ...` to read from standard input instead of using `cat` to set the value of `a`.

Comment: That results in the following:

    user@example:~$ curl -d@/home/user/example.txt -X POST https://example.com
    Cannot POST /

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `curl` command line syntax in all of the above examples seems problematic.  Recall that fundamentally, curl's command line looks like `curl [<options>] url1 url2 ... urln`.  That is, anything that is not an option or an argument to an option is treated as a URL.  So if you have:

```
curl -X POST -d 'test' example.com /home/user/test.txt https://example.com
```

You have *three* non-option arguments: `example.com`, `/home/user/test.txt`, and `https://example.com`.  That's why you're seeing `curl` trying to fetch a URL three times:

The first:

```
100    18  100    14  100     4    127     36 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--   128
```

The second:

```
curl: (3) <url> malformed
```

The third:

```
100    18  100    14  100     4     33      9 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--    40
```

That "malformed url" errors come from trying to fetch `/home/user/test.txt`:

```
$ curl /home/user/test.txt
curl: (3) <url> malformed
```

You don't say which pastebin service you're running in your question, but if it's [haste](https://github.com/seejohnrun/haste-server) then your `curl` command should look something like this:

```
curl --data-binary @/home/user/test.txt -X POST https://hastebin.com/documents
```

The above sends the file `/home/user/test.txt` to hastebin.  The `@<filename>` syntax is how you tell curl to read data from a file; see the `curl` man page for more information.  The return value from the above is a JSON document containing the new document key:

```
{"key":"dudidadoma"}
```

Comment: You are correct in assuming it's a haste. I tried the command you suggested and this is what I get:

user@example:~$ curl --data-binary @/home/user/example.txt -X POST https://example.com
Cannot POST /

The explanation you provided does make sense. I'm still working out how to get this to POST correctly.

If you're wondering, it's at https://paste.ituralde.com

Comment: If it's configured like `hastebin.com` you need to post to `/documents`, as in my example.

Comment: Unfortunately, no. It's configured as subdomain.example.com; no subfolders or anything of that sort. I could try /documents. Will post back shortly.

Edit: Well, shit. I `curl`'d to `/documents` and it works... exactly as you said. I'd prefer not to do it that way, though...